# Matching exactly one node from each graph

Tags: neo4j

I have a database with many small graphs. I need to match exactly one node from each graph. Doesn't matter which node.
`MATCH p=(n)-[*1..]-(m) with head(nodes(p)) as h return distinct h`
This apparently doesn't work because nodes(p) is not sorted, and I cannot think of any other solution.

Comment: How can you identify your subgraphs ? Can you provide a better visualisation of your current graph. thx

Comment: Graphs are independent, not connected to each other. They consist of 2 to 5 nodes. I want to match any of those nodes, for each graph.

Comment: So you don't have any labels or property to identify in which subgraph you are ?

Comment: No. They are all the same anyway.

Comment: I think it will be very hard to find unique subgraphs at runtime without having an entry point in your graph to identify your subgraphs. In other words: At runtime your need to keep track of all subgraphs that are already returned. That will take a lot of heap space to store that information during the query. Can you share your model and use case in a functional way? Maybe we can figure out a good model than.

Comment: It's just one-time maintainence. Trying to remodel an existing graph.

Comment: Is the connectedness of each independent graph arbitrary? That is, are there chains, stars, closed polygons, multiple-interlinks, etc?

Comment: Yes. The connectedness of each independent graph is arbitrary.